# Reordering of a symmetric matrix to create clusters

Tags: python, matrix, cluster-analysis

There probably is name for the process or method I am looking for, but have not been able to find it. I have described it as best I could below.

I am looking for a process that reorders a symmetric matrix in terms of clusters, for example:

[image: Matrix]

In order words it tries to group the indices by some measure. So if you were to split up the resulting matrix in sub-matrices, in the example above A and D are as 'positive' as possible while B and C are as 'negative' as possible.

[image: Submatrices]

Is there a name for this process? What would a computationally efficient approach be to implement this? (I plan to use it for quite large structures in Python). Any pointers very welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use e.g. **single-linkage clustering**.

This is commonly used to reorder matrixes.

In *biclustering*, this is often applied to both rows and columns; here you would only compute it once and apply it to both.